# VUEX: can't get a recent store value

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am using Vuex and Axios together. And after dispatching an action I need to get an error message from response. I don't understand why do I get the correct response only after the second call.

Here I dispatch then use a getter.

```
this.$store.dispatch('registerUser', this.user);

this.errorMessage = this.getError;
console.log(this.errorMessage);
```

Getter is called in computed like this

```
  ...mapGetters({getError:"getErrorMsg"}),
```

The action with API call via Axios

```
 registerUser({commit}, user) {
        const form = new URLSearchParams();
        form.append('login', user.login);
        form.append('password', user.password);
        form.append('email', user.email);
        form.append('firstName', user.firstName);
        form.append('lastName', user.lastName);
        form.append('roles', user.roles);

        Axios.post(userUrl + '/create', form, config)
            .then(
                (response) => {
                    commit('setUser', response.data);
                    if (response.status === 206) {
                        commit('setErrorMessage', response.data);
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    commit('setErrorMessage', error.response.data);
                });

    }
```

So, how to get a correct message after making a call?

Comment: return axios post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing an AJAX request in your `registerUser` action, therefore it is an asynchronous operation. The `setErrorMessage` mutation is performed at some point in the future once the request has responded which happens *after* you access the `this.getError` getter.

You need to wait for the `registerUser` to finish to allow for the error message to be set before you continue.

I would read up on asynchronous JavaScript concepts like Promises, async/await, etc.

You can fix this by making the following changes. First you need to return the promise returned by `Axios.post()`:

```js
registerUser({commit}, user) {
  // code omitted

  return Axios.post(userUrl + '/create', form, config)
    .then(...)
}
```

Now when you dispatch the action, you need to wait for the promise to settle:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('registerUser', this.user)
  .finally(() => {
    this.errorMessage = this.getError;
    console.log(this.errorMessage);
  });
```

Depending on browser support, instead of [`finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) you may want to use [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).